# Ignore mouseover target?

Tags: javascript, events, draggable

I am using a drag script to move an object along the x axis.

Along that same axis there is another object.

I want to use `onmouseover` so when the cursor is over that object and I'm dragging my object, something happens.

Now, this won't work because while dragging, the dragged object is always over other objects.

How can I make JavaScript ignore the dragged object?

Edit : I use http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-drag-and-drop.html for dragging.

Comment: Are you using a custom drag script or an existing one? What are you using for dragging (div / canvas / ...)? Could you show some code please?

Comment: Edited. Also , I am dragging a div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently encountered this issue and ended up using this jQuery plugin:
http://www.48design.de/news/2009/11/20/kollisionsabfrage-per-jquery-plugin-update-v11-8/

This is great for detecting object collision. **However**, to determine when the *mouse cursor* is over the object, the trick I used was to create a 1x1 absolute inline-block div and always have that be positioned where the mouse cursor is.

So, when the user is dragging, to check and see if objects are colliding, use:

```
if ($('.cursorBlock').collidesWith('.staticBlock')) {
    // objects are colliding
} else {
    // objects are not colliding
}
```

So if you keep the 1x1 `.cursorBlock` with the mouse cursor as you drag, when the cursor is over the `.staticBlock` element, the `.cursorBlock` element will be too, and the collision will be detected, even though the real object you're "dragging" will be between the two.

I know you didn't tag your question with jQuery, but I thought I'd answer anyhow in case this helps you.

Comment: I am writing a webOS app , I'm not quite sure jquery is suitable for this. I might check it out if I'm out of options , thanks.

Comment: The plugin's logic should at least be of some use, if you can't find any other out-of-the-box solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the **ondragenter** event:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx